# Entity framework 6.1.3 impossible to install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

I try to install Entity Framework 6.1.3 to my c# project using nuget but get this error:

> Executing script file 'D:\VisualStudioProjects\Anb.Test\trunks\Anb.Test\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\init.ps1'...
>   & : The term 
>   'D:\VisualStudioProjects\Anb.Test\trunks\Anb.Test\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\init.ps1' is not 
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
>   a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What I have done so far:

1. reinstall visual studio - still same error
2. install lowest version entity framework 6.0.0 - still same error
3. try to change/update powershell - still same error
4. try to edit the init.ps1 script and change from Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath EntityFramework.psd1) to Import-Module .\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1 - still same error
5. move the project to the C:\ root, maybe is problem with the name pf the path or something like that. - still same error.

   6. run the init.ps1 script in powershell. - error the module requires the following Windows Powershell host: 'Package Manager Host'.
   7. Run Import-Module D:\VisualStudioProjects\Anb.Test\trunks\Anb.Test\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psd1 inside Package Manager Console.
      Import work, Enable-Migrations command appear. But when i run Enable-Migrations - error :

> Enable-Migrations command appear. But when i run Enable-Migrations - error : Enable-Migrations : The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
>   the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Enable-Migrations
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

This error stopping me to user Enable-Migration and another Entity Framework commands. 
My system is

- windows 7 x64
- visual studio 2017 community
- Nuget info: Version: 4.2.0.2457
- Entity Framework 6.1.3

Comment: did you try to run vs as an administrator ?

Comment: Have you ensured that your current user account / profile has all the permissions required to execute a powershell script? (IIRC the *"ExecutionPolicy"* must be set to something like *"RemoteSigned"*, otherwise you're basically "not allowed" to execute powershell scripts)

Comment: @tschmit007 I run everything like administrator

Comment: can you install other package, or is it a general problem ?

Comment: @bassfader I tried with RemoteSigned and Unrestricted  still same problem

Comment: @tschmit007 I can install other packages. But i can run power shell scripts. For example when i install newtonsoft json the error  
Appears when the packages try to run a script

Comment: so the problem is probably the one pointed by @bassfader

Comment: @tschmit007 My executionPolicy is unrestricted. In this (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) say Unrestricted - No restrictions; all Windows PowerShell scripts can be run.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to install in an svn repositrory (trunks in the path), m I true ? If yes it sounds a little veird to me. Can you try from a fresh unconnected checkout of your project ?

Comment: @tschmit007  I try to create a new project in C:\ root. Is unversion, unconnect to the svn and not working

Comment: Have you checked your powershell and nuget version in the package manager console? Perhaps old versions are being referenced by visual studio 'internally'.

Comment: @Silvermind My nuget and powershell version is ok. Are updated and the last verision

Comment: @MrBlue, "I tried with RemoteSigned ", Do you mean that you have run the command "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" in the Package Manager Console and not works for you? If not, please try this command. How about create a new user profile, with admin rights, and Ran Visual Studio on that profile, check if it works for you?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Yes. I run the commnad Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned or Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted in nuget package  manager console and not works for me.

Comment: Have you try to  create a new user profile, with admin rights, and Ran Visual Studio on that profile?

Comment: Last solution. I re-install the windows and every thing work. I don't have any ideea why this problem appear. I guess the problem is powershell, never know